# How do I select the last 50 percent rows

Tags: sql-server

I can do a select top 50 percent of the table rows  like this to get the first 50 percent of the records/ rows

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM table_1
```

How do I select the last 50 percent without doing subquery or sorting?

Comment: What's *wrong* with what you have (apart from the omission of an `ORDER BY` clause)? Any other method is likely to be less efficient.

Comment: I need to do a cross join against a very large table. I'm getting a System.OutOfMemoryException. I thinking of getting the first 50 percent on my initial query and the last 50 percent on the next query

Comment: `System.OutOfMemoryException` is an application error, not a SQL Server error. Most likely SSMS (which is a 32bit application) is running out of memory. If you are wanting to export the data from a table, an SSMS query window is the wrong tool.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to do sort on desc on a field

Comment: at least you're not wanting the second 25%! `select top 50 percent * from (select top 50 percent * from table_1) t1 order by id desc` that would have to sort twice!

Comment: Doesn't matter _how you sort it_. If you return all the columns from a million rows to SSMS, it's not going to handle it. It's like trying to put a couch into a backpack.

Comment: Where do the results end up?  I would consider batch processing.  If there is a key, you could process a range in each batch.  SSIS might be something to look at.  Also, if there are a lot of records in both tables, make sure you are joining on the correct columns and not getting close to a cross join.